# Figuring out what is causing the kernal panic on Macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, kernel-panic

Figuring out what is causing this panic attack..
Can anybody help me with this?

```
Panic (system crashes) log:

  Source:   /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Kernel_2014-11-05-230220_Kisuke.panic
  Size: 9 KB (9,495 bytes)
  Last Modified:    05/11/14 11:02 pm
  Recent Contents:  Anonymous UUID:       98CDEB31-C8B5-908E-FBB5-E0BF8F63C05F

Wed Nov  5 23:02:20 2014
panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff7f857a0f7c): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 3 0 a0 d9 9 8 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0x102c00000 0xffffff81f5ebd000 0x0e7150a2, D0, P3/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.6.22/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81f511ad70 : 0xffffff8003422f79 
0xffffff81f511adf0 : 0xffffff7f857a0f7c 
0xffffff81f511aec0 : 0xffffff7f83e9eba4 
0xffffff81f511af80 : 0xffffff7f83f68ebe 
0xffffff81f511afc0 : 0xffffff7f83f68f2e 
0xffffff81f511b030 : 0xffffff7f8419e106 
0xffffff81f511b0c0 : 0xffffff7f841b5505 
0xffffff81f511b100 : 0xffffff7f83fe169b 
0xffffff81f511b130 : 0xffffff7f83fe1625 
0xffffff81f511b160 : 0xffffff7f840ed0cf 
0xffffff81f511b190 : 0xffffff7f840eeda1 
0xffffff81f511b230 : 0xffffff7f840ef368 
0xffffff81f511b2b0 : 0xffffff7f83eb3a03 
0xffffff81f511b300 : 0xffffff7f840f3587 
0xffffff81f511b460 : 0xffffff7f840f3a2a 
0xffffff81f511b4e0 : 0xffffff7f83fa0822 
0xffffff81f511b6b0 : 0xffffff7f83f9f3c3 
0xffffff81f511b6f0 : 0xffffff7f83faf52c 
0xffffff81f511b750 : 0xffffff7f83fa9997 
0xffffff81f511b770 : 0xffffff7f83f65c7e 
0xffffff81f511b7b0 : 0xffffff7f83f64d68 
0xffffff81f511b810 : 0xffffff7f83ea1fe0 
0xffffff81f511b830 : 0xffffff7f83ea29d7 
0xffffff81f511ba50 : 0xffffff7f83ea2cc4 
0xffffff81f511baf0 : 0xffffff7f83e50400 
0xffffff81f511bb70 : 0xffffff7f83e4fc6e 
0xffffff81f511bbd0 : 0xffffff7f83e51596 
0xffffff81f511bc10 : 0xffffff7f83e06405 
0xffffff81f511bca0 : 0xffffff7f83dfe635 
0xffffff81f511bce0 : 0xffffff7f83e52158 
0xffffff81f511bd30 : 0xffffff8003898083 
0xffffff81f511bd90 : 0xffffff80038cd5f5 
0xffffff81f511be00 : 0xffffff80034b649b 
0xffffff81f511be50 : 0xffffff8003426bc1 
0xffffff81f511be80 : 0xffffff80034139c5 
0xffffff81f511bef0 : 0xffffff800341e013 
0xffffff81f511bf70 : 0xffffff80034c9b9d 
0xffffff81f511bfb0 : 0xffffff80034f4196 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[75D81741-64C1-3941-ADFA-9D6B6C434EE4]@0xffffff7f83df5000->0xffffff7f83e2cfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[2852ACFE-FD28-3C37-9B39-885201BB8D25]@0xffffff7f83b4b000
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.6.22)[32862231-50BC-3AF6-87A2-703321AE4F90]@0xffffff7f85792000->0xffffff7f857a5fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.6.22)[AA46D551-BE0F-33DA-93A3-8F46197BB36F]@0xffffff7f8578a000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[045D5D6F-AD1E-36DB-A249-A346E2B48E54]@0xffffff7f84783000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[2852ACFE-FD28-3C37-9B39-885201BB8D25]@0xffffff7f83b4b000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[75D81741-64C1-3941-ADFA-9D6B6C434EE4]@0xffffff7f83df5000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.0.4)[80899285-3952-30DA-A0F9-357C51E104CF]@0xffffff7f8578d000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(8.2.6)[272B6397-FEDB-32FC-9035-BDD749284455]@0xffffff7f83e4e000->0xffffff7f840c1fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[2852ACFE-FD28-3C37-9B39-885201BB8D25]@0xffffff7f83b4b000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[D41125CE-69BD-32E7-9B1D-4E83431662DD]@0xffffff7f83e38000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[75D81741-64C1-3941-ADFA-9D6B6C434EE4]@0xffffff7f83df5000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.6.22)[91D61DEC-2946-3790-8134-B808C016C4C9]@0xffffff7f83e48000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal(8.2.6)[EF73AF59-A574-3A5A-B410-7E4F2DA819B0]@0xffffff7f840cd000->0xffffff7f84279fff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(8.2.6)[272B6397-FEDB-32FC-9035-BDD749284455]@0xffffff7f83e4e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[2852ACFE-FD28-3C37-9B39-885201BB8D25]@0xffffff7f83b4b000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
13F34

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 9477416E-7BCA-3679-AF97-E1EAAD3DD5A0
Kernel slide:     0x0000000003200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8003400000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 4211721402
last loaded kext at 3988760829: com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0 (addr 0xffffff7f84f17000, size 45056)
loaded kexts:
com.symantec.kext.ips   3.5f2
com.symantec.kext.ndcengine 1.0f2
com.symantec.kext.internetSecurity  5.2f2
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.7f3
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.34
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.0.9d7
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   2.6.3f4
com.apple.GeForce   8.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.2.7f3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.6.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.7f3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   8.2.8
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.4.11
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup    8.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.6.22
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 8.2.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 1.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck    380.70.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeLZVN 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    683.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.5.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.8.1b2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   683.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 217.92.1
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   217.92.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 98.23
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    8.2.6
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  8.2.6
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.6.3f4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.7fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.7f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.7f3
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91.1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.8
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.7.1d6
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.6.22
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    98.23
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.6.22
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.6.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.10
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  656.4.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    380.70.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    2.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 3.3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b4
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   640.36
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 660.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 686.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.11.1
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  23
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
```

Comment: It says it is your Graphics controller, but it does not say why.

Comment: Your Nvida is causing it, but we need to find out why. If you run without graphics switching or in Safe mode does it work then?

Comment: Using gfxcardstatus and I can still see the problem.

Comment: So disabling the Nvidia does not help ? hmmm...there is also the "symantec" that could do it? disable for now the Norton virus app.

Comment: Not due to symantec..Possible its a hardware issue?

Comment: Did the Apple Hardware test show anything?

Comment: Did two comprehensive tests and nothing..Does that mean hardware is not the issue then..

Comment: I would have done the Extended hardware test. The Apple hardware test is not 100%. Your log clearly shows Graphics problems. Reset the NVRAM, and SMC and start in Verbose mode to check. http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255  if no progress, use cmd-r to restore the OS X.

Comment: I did extended test twice ..